# dfs.block.size has no influence on the performance of TeraGen

Tags: hadoop

I changed the dfs.block.size from 64MB to 1MB in the hdfs-size.xml, and run teragen to explore the influence on job performance. However, the number of map tasks was not changed (I think it should become large, since it is equal with the file size/block size). Also, the time needed to complete the job is almost the same. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

TeraGen is for generation of data. So basically this works off no input to generate data for TeraSort.

So basically no. of mappers is not influenced by block size in this case.

Comment: If you want to influence performance in this case try increasing the no of reducers.

Comment: Thank you very much. You answer really helps. TeraGen has no input, and only produces data for TeraSort. But I have a question here. I found that the completion time of TeraGen was different when I use different dfs.block.size for the generated data, but the change was not monotonous. Is that because larger dfs.block.size will reduce the load of namenode, but will also reduce total throughput for parallel access?? Thanks again.

Comment: A higher block size will mean lesser mappers and consequently more input to each mapper to process. Namenode seek performance will go down if you have too many small files.